# single quotes in php myadmin

Tags: php

in my phpadmin  i try to wite a simple query every time make mistake but if copy query from my phpadmin query  this query sucess i try it alot and i find wronk is what is different
between two word which i copy ((((((((`food`)))))))))) sucess in query  but if write ((((((((('food')))))

in write code

```
$query = "SELECT  'calories'
FROM `food`
ORDER BY 'id' ";
```

in worng code

```
$query = "SELECT  'calories'
FROM 'food'
ORDER BY 'id' ";
```

this faced me in all applications but i try it in simple to know this faster

Answer (score 4):

In your first case, you're using backticks, in the second case, you're using single quotes. You need to use backticks to enclose the table name (if you're going to use a character to enclose the table name). Otherwise, it's not necessary unless your table name is also a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.

In summary, this is OK:

```
`food`
```

Because it's backticks (next to the <kbd>1</kbd> key on a QWERTY keyboard), not single quotes.

This is not OK:

```
'food'
```

Because it's single quotes.

Comment: Next to the `z` on Mac keyboards.